# memcached.service is active, but in the haproxy web page they are down

Tags: memcached, haproxy

The three nodes `memcached.service` is active(running):

```
[root@ha-node3 my.cnf.d]# systemctl status   memcached.service
● memcached.service - memcached daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-08-02 01:01:29 CST; 6min ago
 Main PID: 13329 (memcached)
   CGroup: /system.slice/memcached.service
           └─13329 /usr/bin/memcached -p 11211 -u memcached -m 1024 -c 8192 -l 127.0.0.1,::1,10.10.0.101 -t 4 -I 10m

Aug 02 01:01:29 ha-node3 systemd[1]: Started memcached daemon.
Aug 02 01:01:29 ha-node3 systemd[1]: Starting memcached daemon...
```

but in the haproxy web, the three nodes all is down.

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

I found the `Memcache_Servers` configuration in the `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` the port is `22122`(I write wrong), so I changed to `11211`, and restart the haproxy, but still not work.

```
listen Memcache_Servers
  bind 45.117.40.168:11211
  balance roundrobin
  mode   tcp
  option  tcpka
  server ha-node1 ha-node1:11211 check inter 10s fastinter 2s downinter 2s rise 30 fall 3
  server ha-node2 ha-node2:11211 check inter 10s fastinter 2s downinter 2s rise 30 fall 3
  server ha-node3 ha-node3:11211 check inter 10s fastinter 2s downinter 2s rise 30 fall 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the final, I found the ip in my hosts is like below:

```
[root@ha-node1 sysconfig]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.8.101 ha-node1 ha-node1.aa.com
192.168.8.102 ha-node2 ha-node2.aa.com
192.168.8.103 ha-node3 ha-node3.aa.com
45.117.40.168 ha-vhost devops.aa.com
192.168.8.104 nfs-backend backend.aa.com
```

But in my `/etc/sysconfig/memcached`, the ip is not the host ip before, so I changed to the ip in the hosts, you see below snapshot:

[image]

Now I restart the memcached and haproxy, it works normal now.

[image]